# MySQL Populate a new field with query results from another field in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, bigdata, sql-insert

I have a large (1 million + row) database/table that includes a "Name" field. However, I need a firstname and lastname field.

I am able to run queries to display the fist and last names the way I need them in the new fields (parsing), but I can't seem to get those query results to INSERT into the table.

I was able to create the fields in the table, but not populate them.

I am working in phpMyAdmin, and the table was exported from Access via ODBC.

A couple examples of code that doesn't work are below. It's been a few years since I had to work with SQL and I think maybe the logic of this approach is just wrong. I certainly appreciate any help.

Example that doesn't work:

```
INSERT INTO fed2012_aquabarndesign_com (lastname)
select left(Name,InStr(Name,',')) AS lastname
from fed2012_aquabarndesign_com
```

or

```
INSERT INTO fed2012_aquabarndesign_com (lastname)
Values (select left(Name,InStr(Name,',')) from fed2012_aquabarndesign_com);
```

Comment: Are you trying to reinsert those records or just split your full name field into first name and last names (UPDATE)?

Comment: I was trying to reinsert the records. The thought was to delete the "name" field after the others were generated...But I am wide open to suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can do it with an `UPDATE` -- not sure you want to `INSERT` those records back to the same table:

```
update fed2012_aquabarndesign_com
set firstname = trim(left(name, instr(name, ' ' ))),
  lastname = trim(right(name, length(name) - instr(name, ' ' )))
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe511/1)

This does assume each full name has a space in between the first name and last name fields.

If you *really* want to reinsert those rows, then this should work:

```
insert into fed2012_aquabarndesign_com (firstname, lastname)
select trim(left(name, instr(name, ' ' ))),
   trim(right(name, length(name) - instr(name, ' ' )))
from fed2012_aquabarndesign_com;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7412a/1)

Comment: You are the greatest human to ever live! That worked perfectly!

Comment: @WesCook -- np in the least, glad I could help!